# I am having trouble to updating the packages using apt-get update in parrot 3.4

Tags: updates, apt-get

Thses errors occurs when i execute apt-get update.

> GPG error: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring Release: The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
>   W: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring
>   Release' is not signed.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.

Comment: This is probably because Raring Release is end-of-life. What research have you done regarding this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have manually added some external (unofficial) repositories that will prevent you from updating the packages list

edit /etc/apt/sources.list or any other file in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder and remove any reference to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu from them